# MFC Dynamic Creation + Multiple Inheritance + Using base class pointer?

Tags: mfc, multiple-inheritance

I was trying to add a common base class to various CView items to simplify things but got weird results.  Example Below:

Header:

```
#pragma once

class CParams;

class CCommonBase
{
  public:
  //virtual ~CCommonBase() {};

  virtual void DrawMyView(const CParams *params)=0;

};

class CMyView : public CEditView, CCommonBase
{
    DECLARE_DYNCREATE(CMyView)

    protected:
        CMyView();           // protected constructor used by dynamic creation
        virtual ~CMyView();

    public:
        virtual void DrawMyView(const CParams *params);
};
```

Code:

```
IMPLEMENT_DYNCREATE(CMyView, CEditView)

CMyView::CMyView()
{

}

CMyView::~CMyView()
{
}

void CMyView::DrawMyView(const CParams *params) {
  // ... do whatever ...
}
```

Example Usage in CTabView:

```
// have each view draw itself
CMFCTabCtrl &tabctrl=GetTabControl();
for(int i = 0;i < tabctrl.GetTabsNum();++i)
{
  CCommonBase *view=(CCommonBase*) tabctrl.GetTabWnd(i);
  if (view) {
   // This call ends up doing nothing but calling IMPLEMENT_DYNCREATE(CMyView, CEditView)
   view->DrawMyView(params);
    // Note: When virtual ~CCommonBase() {}; is not commented out the call above 
    // ends up calling the destructor which cases an MFC assert failure 
  }
}
```

The comment in the code above explains what happens.  I can cast to the CMyView class and it works.

Is there a way to have a simple base class added to classes derived from MFC classes and use the base class to call the functions?

TIA!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you use the hard C cast you have no chance. Use `dynamic_cast`

You force that the `CWnd` pointer returned by `GetTabWnd` is used as a `CCommonBase`, but it isn't. It is a `CMyView`.

By using dynamic_cast the internal derivations and vtables are checked. Required is that all classes have a virtual member.`

My advice: Never use the old cast syntax. Use `dynamic_cast`, `static_cast` and if not possible in another way `reinterpret_cast`